# logging unmount for JSX element instead of components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

how we can observe if a JSX element mounted or not. for example I have a simple component with `useEffect` on. it inside of my `App.js` I can mount and unmount my component and the `useEffect` inside of that component will log if it is mounted or unmounted.
but I wonder if there is way to that with JSX elements. for example , can we implement that for an `h2` tag inside of an `App.js` without creating component ?

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Mycomponent from "./Mycomponent";
const App = () => {
  const [mount, setMount] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <b>Mounting and Unmounting</b>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setMount(!mount);
        }}
      >
        {mount ? "click to unmount" : "click to mount"}
      </button>
      {mount && <Mycomponent />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Mycomponent.js :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Mycomponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted");
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>component mounted</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mycomponent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use callback refs for that:

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);        

  const measuredRef = (node) => {
    if (node == null) {
      console.log('I was removed');
    } else {
      console.log('I was mounted');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      }}
    >
      {counter % 2 == 0 && <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>}
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is a somewhat related [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) in the docs about that:

> In this example, the callback ref will be called only when the
> component mounts and unmounts, since the rendered `<h1>` component stays
> present throughout any rerenders.

Comment: Thank you so much 